# How do I schedule a process' termination?

Tags: python, bash, unix, process, kill

I need to run a process, wait a few hours, kill it, and start it again.  Is there an easy way that I can accomplish this with Python or Bash?  I can run it in the background but how do I identify it to use kill on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With bash:

```
while true ; do
    run_proc &
    PID=$!
    sleep 3600
    kill $PID
    sleep 30
done
```

The `$!` bash variable expands to the PID of the most recently started background process. The `sleep` just waits an hour, then the `kill` shuts down that process.

The `while` loop just keeps doing it over and over.

Comment: Does bash autoreap its children?  This will either leave a bunch of zombies (if bash doesn't autoreap) or you run the risk of sending SIGTERM to an unrelated process (bash autoreaps, freeing up the pid for another process).

Comment: I'm assuming the process doesn't exit (based on the question), in which case the PID won't be re-used before it's killed.

Comment: The process does exit but it is a really long running one.  This solution works great!

Answer (score 3):

This is in Perl, but you should be able to translate it to Python.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

#set times to 0 for infinite times
my ($times, $wait, $program, @args) = @ARGV;

$times = -1 unless $times;
while ($times--) {
    $times = -1 if $times < 0; #catch -2 and turn it back into -1
    die "could not fork" unless defined(my $pid = fork);

    #replace child with the program we want to launch
    unless ($pid) {
        exec $program, @args;
    }

    #parent waits and kills the child if it isn't done yet
    sleep $wait;

    kill $pid;
    waitpid $pid, 0; #clean up child
}
```

Because I am trying to teach myself Python, here it is in Python (I do not trust this code):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import sys
import time

times    = int(sys.argv[1])
wait     = int(sys.argv[2])
program  = sys.argv[3]
args     = []
if len(sys.argv) >= 4:
    args = sys.argv[3:]

if times == 0:
    times = -1

while times:
    times = times - 1
    if times < 0:
        times = -1

    pid = os.fork()

    if not pid:
        os.execvp(program, args)

    time.sleep(wait)

    os.kill(pid, 15)
    os.waitpid(pid, 0)
```

Comment: The process id can't be used by another process because the child has not been reaped by the parent yet (it is a zombie).

Answer (score 2):

In python:

```
import subprocess
import time

while True:    
    p = subprocess.Popen(['/path/to/program', 'param1', 'param2'])
    time.sleep(2 * 60 * 60) # wait time in seconds - 2 hours
    p.kill()
```

`p.kill()` is python >= 2.6.

On python <= 2.5 you can use this instead:

```
os.kill(p.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```

Comment: I get NameError: name 'subprocess' is not defined

Comment: Adding import subprocess results in AttributeError: 'Popen' object has no attribute 'kill'

Comment: @chas. owens: p.kill() is for python >= 2.6.

Answer (score 0):

One idea: Save the process's PID (returned by `fork()` in your child process) to a file, then either schedule a `cron` job to kill it or kill it manually, reading the PID from the file.

Another option: Create a shell script wrapper that automatically kills and restarts the process. Same as above, but you can keep the PID in memory, sleep for as long as you need, kill the process, then loop.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [start-stop-daemon](http://olympus.het.brown.edu/cgi-bin/man/man2html?start-stop-daemon) utility.

Comment: ...I fixed it to one that works, but you should check it's the right page you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You could always write a script to search for those processes and kill them if found.
Then add a cronjob to execute the script.

[Find process ID of a process with known name](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part3/section-10.html)

[Kill processes with a known ID](http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/5245-script-kill-all-child-process-given-pid.html)

In python [os.kill()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.kill) can be used to kill a process given the id.

Answer (score 0):

Not an ideal method but if you know the name of the program and you know it's the only process of that name running on the system you can use this in cron:

```
0 */2 * * * kill `ps -ax | grep programName | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $1 }'` && ./scriptToStartProcess
```

This will run every two hours on the hour and kill programName then start the process again.