# execute shell process in Python 2.5

Tags: python, shell, process, command, python-2.5

I need to run `tcpdump`, kill it after a bit and read from stderr.
The following code works in **Python 2.7**, but I need to make it work in **Python 2.5** too::

```
tcpdumpProcess = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', '/usr/sbin/tcpdump',
                        '-w', 'dumpedTraffic.pcap',
                        '-n', 'ip'],
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
tcpdumpProcess.terminate()    
tcpdumpProcess.wait()
tcpdump_stderr =  tcpdumpProcess.communicate()[1]
```

Python **2.5** complains that:

> tcpdumpProcess.terminate()     AttributeError: 'Popen' object
>   has no attribute '**terminate**'

What's en equivalent way of doing it in Python 2.5?

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/704203/1983854

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use os.kill method to terminate the process.

```
os.kill(tcpdumpProcess.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can execute the Kill command along with processid as same as u execute the previous command.

or

u can use the kill methods provided in the os module along with the process id and the signal status such as TERM etc.